# json dump multiple dictionaries

Tags: json, dictionary, python-3.6

I have these 3 dictionaries based on a large data set I have made.  I need to have them saved to a json file but I don't know where to start.

```
result1 = {codes[i]: ucr_ncic_code[i] for i in range(len(ucr_ncic_code))}    
result2 = {districts[i]: district[i] for i in range(len(district))}
result3 = {beats[i]: beat[i] for i in range(len(beats))}
```